# Add Citizens2 Sentry to team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two teams, Red and Blue, that have sentries on them. The sentries have different names for each individual. Is there a way to add sentries to a team so I can use /sentry target add team:name instead of having to add each individual name by hand?

Comment: Can you tell us what mods you are using?

Comment: It's in the title. Citizens2 with Sentry/Sentries.

Comment: nvm fam figured it out ;)

Answer (score -2):

Citizens sentry still count as valid objects for `/scoreboard` team purposes.

Its not shown in the documentation at all, but you can totally do it.

Comment: sup with all these autists downvoting but not commenting why theyre doing that? am I on reddit?